# jquery selector for start with but only certain length/level children?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='1_1'></div>
<div id='1_1_1'></div>
<div id='1_1_2'></div>
<div id='1_2'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
<div id='2_1'></div>
<div id='2_2'></div>
<div id='2_2_1'></div>
```

Given this (psuedo) set of tags, I would like to be able to get all of the "level below" tags.
e.g.

`id=1` gets `1_1` and `1_2`, but not `1_1_1` etc.
`id=2_2` gets `2_2_1` etc

I have tried the `div[id^=1]` but this returns all levels below.
Note, these are NOT nested tags, so Children doesn't work :(

How can I restrict to just `id_`?

e.g. `div[id=1_1_?]`

Is there a single character wildcard, or a way of restricting the length of the selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the attribute starts-with selector you mentioned, and then [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the results:

```
var elems = $("div[id^='1']").filter(function() {
    return this.id.length <= 3; 
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5E9b8/). Note that this also returns the `div` with just `1` as it's `id`. You could prevent that by adding another condition to the `return` statement:

```
var elems = $("div[id^='1']").filter(function() {
    return this.id.length <= 3 && this.id.length > 1; 
});
```

Finally, note that `id` values cannot start with a number unless you're using the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: Was in the process of writing something similar, but this should do it.  Keep in mind you'll have to modify the `<= 3` as you change the `id^='1'`.

Comment: Modified slightly: look for ^=1_ which removes the first 1, then by putting Id into a var, can check for "len <= id.length+2" and "len > id.length".